# Webpack Module Federation Error: Unsatisfied version ^30.3.0 of shared singleton module react-query (required ^3.30.0)

Tags: webpack, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

i'm getting the following error when i load my react-query dependency: (i get similar errors for other libraries)

```
Error: Unsatisfied version ^30.3.0 of shared singleton module react-query (required ^3.30.0)
```

In both my shell app and MFE, i have the following config:

```
      'react-query': {
        singleton: true,
        eager: true,
        strictVersion: true,
        version: '^30.3.0',
      },
```

And in both application, i have the following in the `package.json`:

```
'react-query': '^3.30.0',
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Setting **strictVersion** to true will cause the application to fail if the MFE does not receives the exact version of the share artifact from the host. If requiredVersion is not specified webpack will try to get the versions not only from your main package.json, but also from any npm package that uses 'react-query' in your node_modules. Have you tried to specify version **requiredVersion** in your webpack config?

```
....
const deps = require('./package.json').dependencies; 
....

plugins: [
  new ModuleFederationPlugin({
    name: 'AppName',
    filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
    remotes: {},
    exposes: { './componentA': './src/components/componentA/componentA.js' },
    shared: {
      ...deps,
      'react-query': {
        singleton: true,
        requiredVersion: deps['react-query'],
      } 
    },
  }),
```